# I am trying to fetch data from a servlet into a jsp using angularjs. However, the ng-click seems to be not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, angularjs, ajax, jsp, servlets

Please find my code below :

angulardemo.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>AJAX with Servlets using AngularJS</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('myApp', [])
        .controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
          $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
            $http.get('AngularServlet',function(data) {
              $scope.person=data;
            },function(failure){
              console.log("failed");
            })
          };

        }]);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <div controller="MyController">
           <button ng-click="getDataFromServer()">Fetch data from server</button>
           <p>First Name : {{person.fname}}</p>
           <p>Last Name : {{person.lname}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Servlet code :

```
package com.controller;
public class AngularServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public AngularServlet() 
   {

   }
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
      HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      //JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

      try {

         PersonalData personData = new PersonalData();
         personData.setFname("Fname");
         personData.setLname("Lname");   

         String json = new Gson().toJson(personData);
         response.setContentType("application/json");
         response.getWriter().write(json);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

PersonalData is a simple class with the getter and setter methods for fname and lname. Now when I run the angularjsp.demo on the server and click on Get Data From Server Method , nothing happens. I am not sure if the ng-click is working properly in the first place. Am I doing something wrong ?

The web.xml is :

```
<web-app>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>AngularServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.controller.AngularServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AngularServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AngularServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Edit 1: I am getting the proper json output on running the servlet manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it. I have tried. Doesn't seem a problem like this.

```
public class PersonalData {
  private String fName;
  private String lName;
//setters getters...
}
```

Try it that way.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js">      </script>
<script>
 angular.module('myApp', [])
 .controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
    $http.get("/AngularServlet").success(function(data){
         $scope.person = data;
    });
  };
 }]);
</script>
```

Access to the data.

```
<p>First Name : {{person.fName}}</p>
<p>Last Name : {{person.lName}}</p>
```

---

And use **ng-controller**.

Answer (score 0):

The way you make a GET request is not the Angular way. Try the following code.

```
  $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
      $http.get('/AngularServlet').then(
          function (response) {
              $scope.person = response.data;
          }, 
          function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          }
      );
  };
```

Comment: I tried with this code. Its still doing nothing. Can you please let me know if there is any way that I can find out if the button click is actually hitting the servlet or not ?

Comment: Have you tested the click event is fired ? You can add `console.log("click event")` before the `$http.get(...)` for detection.

Comment: Yes this is working , everything before the $http.get is working as expected.

Comment: Ok, that's a good thing. That means the problem maybe is the URL. When you deploy the **angulardemo.jsp**, what is the url?

Comment: When I deploy the angulardemo.jsp the URL is : 
http://localhost:8080/AngJSDemo/angulardemo.jsp 
The URL to access to servlet is :
http://localhost:8080/AngJSDemo/AngularServlet .

And yes, its Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

yeah @shaohao lin pointed out use `response.data` (or `data.data` in your case) instead of just `data`. What your $http service returns is an object of type `Response` (with response code, headers, data and stuff) and you need only `data` from it!

Answer (score 0):

**Problem no. 1**

You need to replace `controller` with `ng-controller` inside your `div`.

```
<div controller="MyController"> => <div ng-controller="MyController">
```

**Problem no. 2**

You are using `$http` call in wrong way. Try

```
$http.get('/AngularServlet')
.then(function (res) {
  $scope.person = res.data;
}, function (err) {
  console.log("failed");
};
```

**Problem no. 3**

Since your json has properties `"Fname", "Lname"`, you need to use them inside your app, instead of "fname", "lname", as 'fname' is not same as 'Fname' in javascript.

```
<p>First Name : {{person.Fname}}</p>
<p>Last Name : {{person.Lname}}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've changed both the above suggested changes. No effect :(

Comment: Can you update your question to what your new code looks like?

Comment: Also check Problem no. 3